# UILabel background image in Xcode6 ios8

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uilabel, xcode6

I am trying this way to set a background image to a UILabel

```
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"]];
```

but it seems not working with Xcode 6 (iOS SDK 8) as I am not getting the background image when I  run the application !!

Is there a way to do it with UILabel ?

- **note** :
  the reason I am not changing the type to UIImageView is that I have spent long time fixing the constraints to fit in 4 & 3.5 screens ,and I don't want to repeat the work again

Thanks for the help .

Comment: It should work. Aren't you making the label too small for the image to show up?

Comment: @Malloc even if the label size is smaller than it should be, Shouldn't it shows part of the image? //have you tried it on iOS8 Xcode6?

Comment: Yes, I tried in Xcode6 and Yes it should, but just to make sure the label will fit the image size.

Comment: Also, If you make the label as IBOutlet, make sure it's a strong property.

Comment: @Malloc i make it strong and now it works , make it as an answer so that i can accept it , thank you :)

Comment: Obviously you got other issue preventing the label background from showing up. Double check your constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I just check it and everything should work in Xcode6 (beta 7) and iOS8 as well. Make sure the image you are using really exist and you have its name written correctly. Maybe it's better to use **Images.xcassets**, so you don't have to take care of file names and paths.

My code:

```
UILabel* label = [UILabel new];
label.frame = self.view.bounds;
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon"]];
[self.view addSubview:label];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this code to set the UILabel background image. Tested on XCode 6 - iOS 7 and iOS 8. Make sure that the image exist.

Load the image from app bundle:

```
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"]];
```

or from Documents directory:

```
NSArray *sysPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES );
NSString *docDirectory = [sysPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/imageName.png", docDirectory];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath]];
```